# Jquery listview issue

Tags: jquery-mobile

working . seem 2 value in listview.

```
{"liste":{"TotalRecordCount":"2","xmlns":"","dokuman":[{"id":"2568","titles":"İstanbul Eindhoven"},{"id":"2384","titles":"Kesişen Dünyalar",}]}}
```

not working. not seem 1 value in listview

```
{"liste":{"TotalRecordCount":"1","xmlns":"","dokuman":{"id":"2085","titles":"Fotoğraf Atölyesi"}}}
```

my listview adding code

```
path=data.liste.dokuman;

for (var liindex = 0;liindex<path.length; liindex++){
   // my listview adding value
   }
```

if only record in json , listview not add so not add  1 record.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json should be in proper format if there may be more then one result in any Json array .
so your Json should be like this :

```
{"liste":{"TotalRecordCount":"1","xmlns":"","dokuman":[{"id":"2085","titles":"Fotoğraf Atölyesi"}]}}
```

then your above code will work .
Otherwise get the data in following way for single record JsonObject .

```
var id=data.liste.dokuman.id ;
var titles = data.liste.dokuman.id.titles;
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

work :) thanks @neeraj

```
if(path.length == undefined){
              myNewArray[0]= path;
              console.log("not array")
         }
```